# Как настроить удалённое подключение к MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, ubuntu, putty, tornado

Подскажите, как правильно нужно подключаться к бд MySQL с удалённого сервера?
Ситуация такая:
Есть сервер на xx.xx.xx ip-адресе, на нём есть файл, который должен брать из и вносить информацию в бд MySQL на OpenServer уже на моём локальном ПК, но всё никак не могу подключиться.

Уже открыл подключения в openserver'е, там разрешены все подключения к базе данных, порт так же 3306, так же создал пользователей в нужных БД с ip-адресом сервера, откуда будут идти запросы, но пока то ли я не понимаю как закончить это дело, то ли что-то не так делаю.

Использую так же tornado framework. Код на python. Подключаюсь через терминал PuTTY, сервер на платформе linux, openserver с бд на Windows. Указываю в подключении ip-адрес своего локального ПК, но мне кажется это неверно, так же пробовал указать localhost и 192.168.100.xxx, но всё то же.

[image: Пользователи в БД]

[image: Доступные IP в openserver]
Подключение:

```
db_rest='python_rest'
user_rest='Keko'
host_rest='92.47.xx.xx:3306'
password_rest=''
```

Ошибка:

```
tornado_mysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '92.47.xx.xx:3306' (Stream is closed)")
```